# ZPL: how to print in grayscale

Tags: printing, grayscale, zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

I've a ZQ520 printer and I started learning ZPL from [here](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/software/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf).

I need to print some information in different style, to highlight important data. The problem is that I can't find the instruction to print in **grayscale**.

I'm searching something like this:

```
^XA
^FO50,50^ADN,18,10^FDBlack text^FS
^FO50,100^ADN,18,10^GS25^FDGrayscale text^FS
^XZ
```

Where `^GS` means Gray Scale and not Graphic Symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ZQ520 does not support grayscale. If you are printing from a mobile device your best bet is to create a graphic with the gray text. You can then use the Zebra SDK to convert the bitmap to a form. The SDK will dither the image making it appear grayscale on the printer.